# WebAppInterface in WebView does not call onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-webview

I've a fragment with a WebView inside. I added a custom WebAppInterface that has this method

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void submitCorrect() {
   Log.d("SUBMIT", "submit");
   getActivity().onBackPressed();
   //getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

Debugging i saw that the method is called but, I don't know why, neither onBackPressed or popBackStack are working.
Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, calling the onBackPressed method on WebView Thread, You should call it in the main thread. That's the reason it's not working.

Try changing the code as below:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps finishing the activity instead will work:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void submitCorrect() {
   Log.d("SUBMIT", "submit");
   Activity activity = getActivity();
   if (activity != null) 
       activity.finish();
}
```

Comment: It's not what I want. I've a main activity in my app and I'm handling all the stuff with fragments, if I call finish my app will close.

Comment: So what does your onBackPressed() do? Can you share that code, perhaps the problem is in there.

Comment: It's a simple super.onBackPressed() but in other fragments it works.

Comment: And in which Activity are you using? (FragmentActivity, AppCompatActivity...)

Comment: AppCompatActivity with a DrawerLayout

Comment: Yes it does! that's why I can't understand

Comment: So the next thing to do is to make sure that you are actually getting the right activity - If I were you, I would override onBackPressed() in the activity and make sure I am actually hitting it the same way both when you press back button and when you call it explicitly.